# Trying to stop a bank program from ending after a transaction has been chosen. C++

Tags: c++, string, variables, if-statement, getline

I have made a beginner's bank program which allows users to check balance, make deposits and withdrawals.However, every time an option to do something is picked, the transactions occurs and I cannot keep the program "alive" in order for the user to make another transaction. How do I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;


int restart() ;
int main(){

float balance = 10.50 ;
float with ;
float deposit ;
string input ;


cout << "Welcome to your mom's Bank " << endl  ;

cout << "Your current BALANCE is: " << balance << "$" << endl ;
cout << "...how can we help you?" << endl ;
cout << endl ;
cout << "For a withdrawal, enter A. "<< endl ;
cout << "For a deposit, enter B. " << endl ;
cout << "For a balance check, enter C. " ;
cout << endl ;
cout << endl ;
getline(cin, input) ;

    if(input == "B")
            {
    cout << "How much would you like to deposit? " << endl ; 
    cout << "\t\t\t " ;
    cin >> deposit ;
    balance = balance + deposit ;

    cout << "You have deposited " <<deposit<< "$ " <<  endl ;
    cout << "Your current balance is " <<balance<< "$ " ;
    getline(cin , input) ;


    } 
        else if(input == "A")
        {
    cout << "How would you like to withdraw?" << endl ;
    cout << "\t\t\t" ;
    cin >> with ;

    balance = balance - with ;
    cout << "Your current balance is " <<balance<<"$ " ;
    getline(cin , input) ;


    } 
         else if(input == "C")
        {
    cout << "Your current balance is: " << balance << "$ " ;
    getline(cin , input) ;
}else
    {return -1 ; 
  } 



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a loop function such as do..while.

```
string input ;
do{
cout << "Welcome to your mom's Bank " << endl  ;
```

and in the end..

```
}else
  {
                return -1 ; 
  } 
}while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put your program in a loop of some sort. A `while` loop is a pretty good choice for this.

Process their input, and if they exit, you exit your while loop. Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/).

The basic idea:

```
Startup Code
While Keep_Running==true
if they typed exit
    Keep_Running==false (or use a `break`)
  ...   
  Your banking stuff
  ...
End of while loop
Cleanup code
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. thank you , so I can simply use a bool variable to keep this program running. Don't know how I didn't think of this before, but, experience has been gained! Thanks!